# Eliminar registro de mysql con php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, web

Que tal buen día!
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y me veo con la necesidad de borrar archivos de una lista, renglón por renglón, el detalle es que para que esto sea efectivo, el registro también debe eliminarse de la base de datos. Alguna sugerencia de como poder hacer ese match con un botón de borrar renglón y al mismo tiempo borrar el registro??.
 parte del código es el siguiente:

```
    <table id="aa">
        <tr class="uno" >
            <td><b>titulo</b></td>
            <td><b>descripcion</b></td>
            <td><b>nombre</b></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    include 'PDF/baterias/config.inc.php';
    $db=new Conect_MySql();
        $sql = "select*from baterias";
        $query = $db->execute($sql);
        while($datos=$db->fetch_row($query)){?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $datos['titulo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos['descripcion']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="PDF/baterias/archivo.php?id=<?php echo $datos['id_documento']?>"><?php echo $datos['nombre_archivo']; ?></a></td>
            <td><form action="delete.php" method="post" name="frm">
                <button onclick="deleteRow(this)">borrar</button></form></td>   
        </tr>

      <?php  } ?>

    </table>

<script>
function deleteRow(r) {
var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("aa").deleteRow(i);
}
</script>
```

De antemano gracias, saludos!

Comment: Es muy malas práctica entremezclar código PHP con HTML...

Comment: El planteamiento de tu pregunta es algo confuso. Hablas de borrar un _renglón_ y de borrar un registro. Yo entiendo _renglón_  como un conjunto de registros. Debes especificar con más claridad lo que quieres, y cómo estás presentando los datos. Por ejemplo: _"tengo una serie de registros que presento por filas en una tabla, cada uno con un botón `borrar` al lado. Necesito que al presionar en ese botón me borre el registro correspondiente..."_ Si no explicas el contexto nos obligas a adivinar casi todo y así es muy difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Usas algún framework como AngularJS o biblioteca como jQuery o lo prefieres en JavaScript puro?

Comment: Estoy usando solo javascript

Answer (score 4):

Yo lo que haría sería con php y mysql de la siguiente manera:
Aparte de no mezclar html php de esa manera (aunque eso es cuestión de gustos) Pasar con el button el idbateria o un identificador único que utilices, para después en el archivo borrar.php poder hacer un Delete from...where identificador sea esa variable que le pasas mediante post.

```
<?php
echo"<table id='aa'>
        <tr class='uno' >
            <td><b>titulo</b></td>
            <td><b>descripcion</b></td>
            <td><b>nombre</b></td>
        </tr>";
include 'PDF/baterias/config.inc.php';
$db=new Conect_MySql();
$sql = "select*from baterias";
$query = $db->execute($sql);

while($datos=$db->fetch_row($query))
    {
    echo "<tr>
             <td>";
    echo        $datos["titulo"];
    echo    "</td>
             <td>";
    echo        $datos['descripcion'];
    echo    "</td>
             <td>
                 <a href='PDF/baterias/archivo.php?id=";
    echo $datos["id_documento"];
    echo        "'>";
    echo          $datos['nombre_archivo'];
    echo        "</a>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <form action='delete.php' method='post' name='frm'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="idbateria" value=" .'$datos["identificadordefila"]'. " />
                     <button type='submit'>borrar</button>
                 </form> 
             </td>
             </tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Despues en borrar.php hacer el correspondiente borrado de fila:

```
//Conectar...

mysql_connect("localhost","tu_user","tu_password");

//Seleccionar base de datos...

mysql_select_db("mi_base_datos");

//Creamos la sentencia SQL y la ejecutamos

$sSQL="Delete From baterias Where titulo='$datos[titulo]'";
mysql_query($sSQL);
...
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo en estos casos suelo enviar un parámetro identificativo (En este ejemplo usaré el ID) mediante la misma URL al código que ejecutará la eliminacion, quedando la URL algo así: eliminar_perfil.php?id=1 donde ***1*** sería pasado mediante un echo, que desde el código la URL se estructuraría así: `<a href="eliminar_perfil.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>` y pues ya en el otro código recibo el ID mediante GET y ejecuto la eliminación... Es fácil y rápido, además como puedes ver le doy aspecto de ícono al link usando **Font Awesome**